# Array conversion from old php 4 to 5.6

Tags: php, syntax-error, associative-array

I have this script that fills the array but the php I understand is not compliant with 5.6

```
<?php 
$LANG = array( );

$LANG[create_new_ticket] = "Create New Ticket";
$LANG[ticket_created] = "Your ticket has been created. An email has been sent to you containing the ticket information. If you would like to view your ticket and/or attach files you can do so: <a href=\\\"{\$HD_URL_TICKET_VIEW}?id=\$ticket&email={\$_POST[email]}\\\">\$ticket</a>";
$LANG[fill_in_form] = "To create a new support ticket, please fill out the form below.";
$LANG[required_field] = "* Denotes a required field";

/?>
```

but this way throws as a many

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant create_new_ticket - assumed
'create_new_ticket' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\lang\language.php on line 4

Notice: Use of undefined constant ticket_created - assumed
'ticket_created' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\lang\language.php on line 5

Notice: Use of undefined constant fill_in_form - assumed
'fill_in_form' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\lang\language.php on line 6

Notice: Use of undefined constant required_field - assumed 
'required_field' in D:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\lang\language.php on line 7
```

which is the correct syntax?

Comment: $LANG["create_new_ticket"] or $LANG['create_new_ticket'] enclose the key with single quote or double quote. for numeric key enclosing is not necessary, but for string key, you need to add up quotes.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with "compliance" between versions of PHP.... it's simply to do with the error reporting levels that you have configured on your servers.... this has always issued a notice, but you've disabled displaying notices before now

Comment: Done  , but the warning/error is still there

Comment: What warning/error? You only had notices before

Comment: Ok same "notices" e.g. Notice: Use of undefined constant create_new_ticket - assumed 'create_new_ticket' . I've tried bot ['xx'] and ["xx"]

Comment: Have you changed all of them? There's probably more scattered around the script; the notice should tell you which files and line numbers.... just make sure that they're in quotes (either `"` or `'` will do, though I tend to prefer `'` personally)

Comment: Or if you're running an opcache such as APC, you may need to flush that to pick up the modified scripts

Comment: The error message actually tells you what you're doing wrong, why don't you just fix it? That said, you could also create an array with `array('foo' => 'bar')` instead of creating an empty one and filling it afterwards.

Comment: Hello Ulrich , I've done it, but looks like that the problem is that these scripts doesn't pass the variables between each other in php 5.6 while in php 5.2 they works fine

Comment: Passing variables between scripts has nothing to do with the messages that you've posted: `create_new_ticket` isn't defined as a constant, so PHP considers that you might be a sloppy coder and meant to use a string literal `'create_new_ticket'` instead, and it lets you know what it's assuming with the notice message that you're getting

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you, I'd say I'm not sloppy, instead, I'm a total newbie :-). I've inherit this code. In xampp old fashion, with php 5.2.9 it works, in 5.6 it doesn't :-(. With the development of "experiments" to fix this, I've noticed that the issue is that variables are not passed from includes files to the including ones. May it be possible? Is it some declaration needed? TY in fact also the mysql credentials include file doesn't "work" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The keys you're using should also be strings, not bare words:

```
$LANG['create_new_ticket'] = "Create New Ticket";
$LANG['ticket_created'] = "Your ticket has been created. An email has been sent to you containing the ticket information. If you would like to view your ticket and/or attach files you can do so: <a href=\\\"{\$HD_URL_TICKET_VIEW}?id=\$ticket&email={\$_POST['email']}\\\">\$ticket</a>";
$LANG['fill_in_form'] = "To create a new support ticket, please fill out the form below.";
$LANG['required_field'] = "* Denotes a required field";
```

Comment: Hello Mureinik, I've done the modification but the Notices are still there, can you guess why? Is it matter of something else in the script? Thank you for the replies

Comment: You probably need to apply the same fix on other lines as well. Check the line numbers in the notices you get.

Comment: Unfortunately they are still all the lines :-( and in all th elines, one for each sentence, they are now ['x']

Answer (score 0):

Try with array declaration as per PHP docs.

```
$LANG = [
    "create_new_ticket" => "Create New Ticket",
    "ticket_created" => "Your ticket has been created. An email has been sent to you containing the ticket information. If you would like to view your ticket and/or attach files you can do so: <a href=\\\"{\$HD_URL_TICKET_VIEW}?id=\$ticket&email={\$_POST[email]}\\\">\$ticket</a>",
    "fill_in_form" => "To create a new support ticket, please fill out the form below.";
    "required_field" => "* Denotes a required field",
];
```

Comment: No way, I did it and it throws the same notice , this is making me crazy :-). I suspect now some variables are not passed anymore among the scripts and includes. In fact I notice that also the db connection fails so the db_connect script is not passing the variables anymore "Notice: Undefined variable: db_user"

Comment: Have you tried to check the php logs for further details?

Comment: Ok, I got it, they are the includes that don't pass the variables.

Comment: Ciao Fabrizio, thank you for your assistance, the php log shows the same output as the browser. I've erased the log and refreshed the page, this is the new log http://jpst.it/E-2F

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I've always declared an associative array:

```
$LANG = array(
"create_new_ticket" => "Create New Ticket",
"ticket_created" => "Your ticket has been created. An email has been sent to you containing the ticket information. If you would like to view your ticket and/or attach files you can do so: <a href='{$HD_URL_TICKET_VIEW}?id={$ticket}&email={$_POST['email']}'>{$ticket}</a>",
"fill_in_form" => "To create a new support ticket, please fill out the form below.",
"d_field" => "* Denotes a d field");
```

See [Official PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
You can also a working [snippet](http://viper-7.com/Kkcl1U)

Comment: Ciao Filippo, as written to Fabrizio, looks like these scripts in php 5.6 are not passing the variables of the others php includes files